# rosmake does not find my package

Tags: catkin, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I work on ubuntu 12.04 32 bit ROS groovy.
I have moved my packages to another machine, but even though roscd can find my package, rosmake does not compile. make works ok. The new machine is ubuntu 12.04 64 bit Groovy. I did not have this problem when I did the same on ubuntu 11.10 64 bit Groovy. This is not a path problem. I have verified this.

What it shows:
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['serial_line']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.

Anyway after trying out a lot, I found out that once I delete the file CATKIN_IGNORE in the package directory, rosmake compiles fine. This file is empty though. Any suggestions on why this might happen? What is the proper way to solve this? rosmake --pre-clean did not do the trick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66571/rosmake-does-not-find-my-package/) by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 528 on 2013-07-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-07-04**:
The question would be why do your dry packages have a CATKIN_IGNORE marker file in the first place? Is it part of the repo? Can you provide a link to the repository of these packages?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-07-04**:
Are you using `make eclipse-project`?

**Comment by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on 2013-07-04**:
Hi Dirk, This is my own package; and yes I am using make eclipse-project. But I never had problem compiling my code on a different machine (ubuntu 11.10 64 bit groovy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a released some modification into ros/mk 1.9.49 and catkin 0.5.69 which should fix your issue. Currently they are only available from the building repo. The will be synced into shadow-fixed as soon as all packages have been rebuilt. It would be great if you could validate that these versions fix the issue for you (at best before they are synced to public).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on 2013-07-16**:
Sorry for the late reply. Could you please advice me on how to go about doing this without affecting my current ros installation? Do I create an overlay and install from source?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This could be related to [ros-infrastructure/rospkg/issues/39](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rospkg/issues/39).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2013-07-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1